# Potentiometer - confusion about arrow direction

Tags: potentiometer, pins

[image]

In this schematic, is the left pin of the potentiometer connected to 6 and the middle pin connected to 7 or vice versa?

Comment: the arrow represents  the slider pin (probably, but not necessarily, the middle pin) ... does it look connected to pin 7? ... refer to the potentiometer datasheet for pin configuration

Answer (score 1):

Both the "left" and "middle" pins are connected to pin 6 of the potentiometer. The "right" pin is connected to pin 7.  This is electrically the same as connecting the wiper to pin 6 of the opamp but ensures that an open circuit condition will not occur if contact between the wiper and the track is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The potentiometer is controlling the gain of the amplifier. The usual configuration would be to have gain increase with clockwise rotation of the knob.

In the inverting amplifier configuration the gain is give by by \$ A = - \frac {R_f}{R_i} \$ so we know that increased gain will require increased resistance. That means that at fully clockwise (max gain, max resistance) the wiper should be touching the clockwise tab.

Since the potentiometer is being used as a variable resistor it doesn't matter which way round it goes between pins 6 and 7.